# Changing certain object properties without overwriting the entire object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function, object

I am trying to overwrite an object given specific changes to that object. The problem is that there are other nested objects that get overwritten as well. How would I prevent this?

```
    const deviceChanges = {
        "a": 5,
        "card": {
                "back": [
                    {
                        "key": "iphoneText",
                        "label": "IPHONE",
                        "value": "UPDATED VALUE FOR IPHONE"
                    },
            ]            
        }
    };

    let newBody = {
        "a": 3,
        "card": {
            "back": [
                   {
                    "key": "androidText",
                    "label": "ANDROID",
                    "value": "androidOS"
                   },
                   {
                    "key": "samsungText",
                    "label": "SAMSUNG",
                    "value": "samsungOS"
                   },
                   {
                    "key": "iphoneText",
                    "label": "IPHONE",
                    "value": "iphone"
                   },
                   {
                    "key": "macbookText",
                    "label": "MACBOOK",
                    "value": "macbookOS"
                   }
        ]            
    },
        "c": 8
    };

    const expected = {
        "object": {
            "a": 5,
            "card": {
                "back": [
                    {
                        "key": "androidText",
                        "label": "ANDROID",
                        "value": "androidOS"
                       },
                       {
                        "key": "samsungText",
                        "label": "SAMSUNG",
                        "value": "samsungOS"
                       },
                       {
                        "key": "iphoneText",
                        "label": "IPHONE",
                        "value": "UPDATED VALUE FOR IPHONE"
                       },
                       {
                        "key": "macbookText",
                        "label": "MACBOOK",
                        "value": "macbookOS"
                       }
            ]       
        },
            "c": 8
        }
    };
```

Here is a Unit Test example of what I am trying to do. I want to take the changes object, and basically replace b.x in newBody, but I also want to preserve the other fields like b.y, a, and C. I want to make it as dynamic as possible, so if there is another object for newBody.b.x or another value for A, I want the code to be able to notice that and adequately change that. Does anyone have an idea on what to do here?

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(changes)) {
    for(let [key1, value1] of Object.entries(value)) {
            newBody[key][key1] = value1;
        }
    }
```

This is what I have so far in terms of Code. But it only takes into account the fact that it only needs to traverse through two objects to replace. If I had something like:

```
const changes = {
            "b": {
                "x": "new",
                "y": {
                     "n": "iphone"
                }
            }
        };
```

The code would not work. How do I make it as dynamic as possible to realize how many objects it needs to replace?

Comment: `newBody.b.x = changes.b.x` I sthat what you are expecting ?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but ... you can recursively enumerate the properties of the `changes` object & sub-objects — for each of those set the value in the newBody object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that assigns values for matching keys from a source object into a target. It does so recursively.

[Lodash _merge()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge) does something like this, probably handling many more edge cases than I've anticipated here (which is approximately none).

```js
const changes = {
  "b": {
    "x": "changed",
    "Z": "new key/value pair"
  }
};

let newBody = {
  "a": 3,
  "b": {
    "x": "old",
    "y": "fields"
  },
  "c": 8
};

// overwrite values in target with matching keys in source 
// side-effects target, also returns it
function merge(target, source) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(source)) {
    if (key in target) {
      if (typeof value === 'object' && typeof target[key] === 'object') {
        merge(target[key], value);
      } else {
        target[key] = value;
      }
    } else {
      // the key in source isn't in the target. add it
      target[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return target;
}

const r = merge(newBody, changes)
console.log(r)
```

Comment: If I was to add a new Key to b called Z which wasn't in newBody, this code would not work. How would I modify it to also add the feature of adding that new object in newBody? My issue currently is that its replacing the entire b object with just Z

Comment: Hi @bob - new keys/values can be incorporated straight-forwardly. Please see edit.

Comment: So I am seeing an odd issue. I have updated the code example, but essentially, your code you have written is not working for that example. I am trying to debug what exactly is going on.. It is replacing the "androidText" object with the "iphone" one.. I think its because the first object in the array? How would you fix this?

Comment: The original solution was to replace values for matching keys in objects, including nested. It looks like the edited problem includes arrays, and matches objects partly by *matching values*. It's significantly different in (implied at least) requirements. I can try to remember to work on it later today -- or maybe get new eyes on it with a new question?  (I think it's warranted.  Feel free to drop a link to that here)

Comment: No worries. I have attached the new link [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74438464/changing-object-properties-that-are-nested-in-arrays-and-properties-that-are-not). I hope you have time to answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how deep an object/array is nested you often need to make use of recursive functions (functions that call themselves)

The function I wrote below is that.

I'll try to explain how it works:

For simplicities sake we're gonna assume there is only 1 property per "layer" (the function can actually handle multiple - since we loop, but to explain the recursive part we're just gonna simplify the whole thing)

So you start by checking if the property of the changes object is itself an object or not. If it not an object, this means we are at the deepest level of this particular nesting, so we can replace the property of our actual object with the property of the changes object. If the property is however an object we need to go deeper. So what we do in this case is call the function again but pass only the property object (in our case we would pass `{x: "new"}` and `{x: "old", y: "fields"}` - we do this until we don't find an object as our property in which case we'll replace.

This way we can go however deep we need and replace only properties that are primitives.

```js
const changes = {
  "b": {
    "x": "new",
  }
};

let newBody = {
  "a": 3,
  "b": {
    "x": "old",
    "y": "fields"
  },
  "c": 8
};

function doTheThing(theObject, changes) {
  const keys = Object.keys(changes)
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (typeof changes[key] === "object" && changes[key] !== null) {
      //this will also be true if changes[key] is an array
      doTheThing(theObject[key], changes[key])
    } else {
      theObject[key] = changes[key]
    }
  })
  return theObject
}

console.log(doTheThing(newBody, changes))
```

So we solved that problem with recursion (there are tons of resources about that if you need more information)